# How to take while loop values outside of the loop

Tags: php, variables, while-loop, output

I'm trying to take values from cookie, then escape all commas with `explode()`, and loop all the values from the cookie with a `while` loop.

When I tried to display the values inside the `while` loop using the code below, it works:

```
echo $hey= '<span>'.$result[$counter].'</span>  ';
```

But I need to access the values outside the loop, and this code doesn't give any output.

```
$cookie_value=$_COOKIE["chords"];  
$counter = 0;
$result=explode(",", $cookie_value);

$array_el_lenght = count($result);

while ($counter<=$array_el_lenght) {
  $hey= '<span>'.$result[$counter].'</span>  ';
  $counter++;
}

echo $hey;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your while loop's is looping one time too many, as the last element of your array is at index `$array_el_lenght - 1`. Also, don't forget to concatenate your results (EDIT: I'm just guessing this is what you are trying to do), not just reassign `$hey`! ;-)

Try this:

```
$cookie_value=$_COOKIE["chords"];  
$counter = 0;
$result=explode(",", $cookie_value);

$array_el_lenght = count($result);

$hey = "";
while ($counter < $array_el_lenght) {
  $hey .= '<span>'.$result[$counter].'</span>  ';
  $counter++;
}
echo $hey;
```

Comment: You are missing a semicolon, that code throws a syntax error: $hey = "";
;)

Comment: @mbinette Nowhere in your provided PHP doc link is it stated that loops have their own local scope. If the OP just did a LESS THAN comparison, granted she was not concatenating values to $hey, then she would get something back with the echo statement

Comment: I've corrected the above post. I would delete it but I can't since it's the accepted answer. I've voted Marcos' answer up and do hope OP unaccepts mine and accepts his.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to access to an undefined offset of `$result`, your code is trying to access `$result[count($result)]` which doesn't exist, you need to replace the while statement, so in your last iteration the index is at `count($result)-1`

```
while ($counter < $array_el_lenght) { //Replaced <= with <
   $hey= '<span>'.$result[$counter].'</span>';
   $counter++;
   echo $hey; // will output the current iteration
 }

// echo $hey; //Will output the content of  last while iteration
```

Comment: Doesn't give result either or will have an error. Look at @mbinette answers.

Comment: In his example, $key is empty, beacuse he is trying to access an undefined offset, since he is iterating array_length + 1 times,  @Mureinik answer is wrong, since he's doing the same, the while statement is wrong.

Comment: This is the real answer to the question. It isn't because of scope issues like what others are saying here but because of an undefined offset. Always have error reporting enabled so you can see any fatal errors when developing.

Comment: @georaldc Thanks, i'm getting several down votes and don't know why,  when the other answers were doing the same thing, they all had an undefined offset.

Comment: And It's funny because they are all talking about the scope when it has nothing to do with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`$hey` is defined inside the loop, so its scope ends with the loop. If you want to access it from outside the loop, you should define it outside of it too:

```
$hey = NULL;
while ($counter<=$array_el_lenght) {
    $hey= '<span>'.$result[$counter].'</span>  ';
    $counter++;
}
if ($hey) {
    echo $hey;
}
```